# Check if a class has been instantiated

Tags: php, class

I am trying to figure out how I can check if I have instantiated a class:

```
include("includes/class.parse.php"); // Include the class
$parse = new parse(); // instantiate the class

if(class_exists('parse')){
    echo 'Class instantiated!';
} else {
    echo 'Class NOT instantiated!';
}
```

Whether I comment out the `$parse = new parse();` or not I get "Class instantiated"?

How can I check this?

Comment: If you want to prevent instantiating your class twice, you are looking for the [singleton pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern)

Comment: Note that the term "instantiated" usually refers to _objects being instantiated_, whilst we speak of "defined" for classes. You seem to mix this. If the class is _not_ defined, then you should get a runtime error in line 2. There is little sense in testing that afterwards. If you really want to test if an _object_ of that class has been instantiated, then `class_exists()` does not help. Instead you have to test if the object exists and if it is an instantiation of the class in question (`is_a()` or `get_class()`))...

Comment: Please clarify why you (think you) need this information.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`get_class`](http://php.net/get_class)

```
$parse = new parse(); // instantiate the class

var_dump ( get_class($parse) );  // return false if object is not instantiated
```

Answer (score 8):

You know that you have instantiated a class if you have an object of that type:

```
$parse instanceof parse
```

A class does not keep track how many objects of its type have been instantiated. If you need that, you have to do it yourself:

```
class Foo {

    public static $instances = 0;

    public function __construct() {
        self::$instances++;
    }

}

new Foo;
new Foo;

echo 'Foo has been instantiated ', Foo::$instances, ' times';
```

However, I don't see a reason to do that, it's rather useless information.